# C# WPF - Camera capture from DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, aforge

I'm using AForge.NET library to capture USB Camera,
I need that piece of code to be on a DLL.
For each frame the AForge.NEt library create an event with a bitmap, I'm trying to bubble up this event to my main WPF window, for this I created a simple event in the DLL library so the main app can init this event.
but I'm getting "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."
I'm using

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
   {
       imgCamera.Source = newFrame;
   });
```

still the same message. any idea?

Comment: is the `imgCamera` or the `newFrame` owned by another thread? you should clone the `newFrame` before assigning it to another object

Comment: I tried it. it didn't help.

Comment: my guess would be that a third thread which isn't invoked owns `imgCamera` or `newFrame`. Try to set a breakpoint before and check the threads.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after spending on it so many time.
just do -> 
   newFrame.Freeze();

it takes of all thread issues